# TypeError: on_voice_state_update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a bot that gives members a role while being on a voice channel, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(after.server.roles, name="glosowy")
    if not before.voice.voice_channel and after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.add_roles(after, role)
    elif before.voice.voice_channel and not after.voice.voice_channel:
        await client.remove_roles(after, role)
```

And here's the error I receive:

```
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: on_voice_state_update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Could you please include code on how do you call on_voice_state_update function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot the parameter 'member'

from the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)

```
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)
```

before and after are VoiceState which stand for information on if the member (in parameter) is muted, broadcasting etc... see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicestate)

therefore you can't retrieve role from it you have to get it from the member

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="glosowy")
    if role: # verify their is a role with that name
        if not before.channel and after.channel: # check member just entered a channel
            await member.add_roles(role) #add role to it 
        elif before.channel and not after.channel: # check member just left a channel
            await member.remove_roles(role) # remove role to it
```

Comment: After adding that parameter i received this:
```Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.48.0\Flobot\flo.py", line 31, in on_voice_state_update
    role = discord.utils.get(after.server.roles, name="glosowy")
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'server'```

Comment: this error come from the variable after
after and before is the voice_state telling you if the member from the parameter switch from speaking to muted, etc...
so your function should be something like this 
```
role = discord.utils.get(member.roles, name="glosowy")
```

Comment: @bierzcochcesz I edited my answer can you check ? :)

Comment: Now I didn't receive any errors, but i didn't receive the role from bot as well

Comment: does the role named "glosowy" exist in your channel ?

Comment: I know what's wrong I check from the member.role and he doesn't have it right now I edit my answer sorry ^^'
should have retrieve it from the guild instead !